# Generate PDF with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, pdf

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and I'm trying to generate a PDF download using Snappy PDF.

The reason I am trying to do it this is way is so that I can submit the form data to the PDF without reloading the page.

Here is my blade template:

```
<div>
    Download a PDF: <button type="button" class=" btn-success btn-sm" id="js-download" >Download</button>
</div>
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/download', 'FormController@generatePDF');
```

This is my controller function:

```
public function generatePDF(Request $request)
{
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.download', $request);
    return $pdf->download('download.pdf');
}
```

And this is my .js file:

```
$(document).on("click", "#js-download", function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    url: '/download',
    data: $("#js-pdf-form").serialize(),
    success:function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error:function() {
    }
});

});
```

The PDF works if I call the route via the address bar in the browser, but if I click the button and attempt an AJAX request it fails, however it does console log what seems to be the PDF output...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you saying the ajax returns a successful return code? You should also add a log in the error callback, it helps so much during development.

Comment: I've not worked with downloads much, but from my own common knowledge I would have to say that AJAX does not support downloads, it just retrieves the data. Now if it is actually being successful, and you get the pdf data, you can place that data in an element or something, (at this point I don't know how downloads work so that's all i can tell you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace it:

```
return $pdf->download('download.pdf');
```

to this:

```
$pdf_file = 'download.pdf';

$pdf_path = 'public/pdf/'.$pdf_file;

$pdf->save($pdf_path);

return asset($pdf_path);
```

Dont forget to create the public/pdf folder...

Comment: If it still dont work, return the $pdf_path and on ajax success do this:

window.location=data;